# Parser expression replace

Tags: java

I need to create a parser that modifies the values ​​depending on the input, example condition `dog health < 5 && dog country = spain`, then how to read these conditions and use them in the application, there are many more expressions, not just health or country, which is the best option to do this?, since i think that creating a class for each expression would be very big.

Comment: [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)?

Comment: I'm a big fan of what @BasilBourque suggests, especially if what you need this for is more than a toy academic program. ANTLR is robust, but there's a learning curve.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'll take a look, but if I have these conditions and if return true I want to change the country of the dog using maybe `dog setcountry canada`, is that possible with antlr?

Comment: If you can use othe representations of the conditions, json for example, the parsing part be done with ease.

Comment: If you don't need to use that exact syntax, you could look at drools https://www.javainuse.com/drools_hello (I have never used it, but it looks as though it would do roughly what you want.)